# Customize cursor position in TeXnicCenter autocompletion

Tags: texniccenter, auto-completion

For example, the following in `math.xml` makes possible autocompletion for the `equation` envirionment

```
<lxEnvironment name="equation" 
        parameters="1" 
        desc="Math environment"
        icon="math.bmp"
        index="10"
        expafter="}&#xA;&#xA;\label{eq:}&#xA;\end{equation}" 
        expbefore="\begin{"/>
```

so that when I type `equ` and hit `Ctrl`+`Space`, the following is autocompleted

```
\begin{equation}

\label{eq:}
\end{equation}
```

I want to ensure that after the autocompletion, the cursor stops at a given place, say, after `eq:`. Right now, it stops at the empty line. I was not able to change the behavior by playing with the parameters in the Xml code. I am using TeXnicCenter 2.02.

I vaguely remember it is possible to achieve this effect in TeXnicCenter 1, forgot how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the general rule for the syntax for `lxEnvironment` seems to be the following:

1. the content of variable `expbefore` is printed (results in `\begin{`)
2. the name of the environment, here `equation`, is added. Now we have: `\begin{equation`
3. the content of variable `expafter` is added, with `&#xA;` changed to a newline.
4. At last it seems that the cursor is set to the (first?) blank line or more simple after the closing `}` of `\begin{equation}`.

The given complete code:

```
    <lxEnvironment name="equation" 
        parameters="1" 
        desc="Math environment"
        icon="math.bmp"
        index="10"
        expafter="}&#xA;&#xA;\label{eq:}&#xA;\end{equation}" 
        expbefore="\begin{"/>
```

You can test this by changing the content of `expbefore` for example to `expbefore="\begin{equation}&#xA;&#xA;\label{eq:"` and `expafter` to `expafter="}&#xA;\end{equation}"`.  Then you get `equation` inserted after `...eg:` and the cursor stays at the beginning of the blank line.  I think that is hardcoded in the code of TeXnicCenter.  To get that changed please contact the support of TeXnicCenter, located on the homepage [of TeXnicCenter](http://www.texniccenter.org)

For an easy testing you can for example create an file `mycommand.xls` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<lxCollection version="1" xmlns:txclxp="http://schemas.ToolsCenter.org/TeXnicCenter/LaTeXCommands.xsd">
    <lxPackage name="username" 
        path="" 
        desc="My commands" 
    >
  <lxEnvironment name="testerle" 
            parameters="0" 
            desc="Math environment"
            icon="math.bmp"
            index="10"
            expafter="}&#xA;\end{equation}" 
            expbefore="\begin{equation}&#xA;&#xA;\label{eq:"/>
    </lxPackage>
</lxCollection>
<!-- $Id$ -->
<!-- 
    $Log: username.xml,v $
    First version 2016/09/26 21:00:00 username
    no message

-->
```

and copy it to the system path where Windows installed your TeXnicCenter, for example `C:\Program Files\TeXnicCenter\Packages` (64bit version).

After a restart of TeXnicCenter (close all TeXnicCenter windows, open then a new one) you can test the now loaded new environment `testerle` (to avoid problems with the real needed and installed `equation`) ...